# How to check properties with Json.Net in an Asp.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, validation, json.net

In my web application I have a web service that receives POST requests with JSON data. Using Json.Net I create a JsonSchema for my classes and check wether the incoming data is valid or not. The code looks like this:

```
public bool IsValidRequest(string strInput, out String errText)
{
    List<String> exceptions = new List<String>();
    errText = "";
    strInput = strInput.Trim();

    JsonSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(MyRequestType));            

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(strInput))
    {
        using (JsonValidatingReader reader =  new JsonValidatingReader(new JsonTextReader(sr)))
        {
            reader.Schema = schema;
            reader.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => { exceptions.Add(args.Exception.Message); };

            while (reader.Read()) { }

            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.Count; i++)
                {
                    errText += exceptions[i];
                    if (i < exceptions.Count - 1)
                        errText += "\r\n";
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This works pretty good, but in my classes I use DataAnnotations like this:

```
public class MyRequestType
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ID;  

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public String Name;
}
```

The ValidatingReader checks if the required properties exist and has the right data type, but not if the given range or string length is correct. Is there any way to achieve this using DataAnnotations or do I have to check these properties all by myself?

Comment: DataAnnotations are used by ASP.NET's object validation after the object has been created.  It would be enforced by another round of validation.  In ASP.NET MVC, it's a matter of checking `if(Model.IsValid){}`

Comment: So as I understand it, I have to create an object from the received Json data and check wether its properties are valid or not. There is of course another problem because the built in Validator doesn't support nested object validation, but this is a different topic ;)
Thanks for now!